# let keyword in ES6

Tags: ecmascript-6

Please explain the difference between Both codes. Why Outputs of both are different.

```js
'use strict';
let printNumTwo;
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i;
    };
  }
}
console.log(printNumTwo());
```

```js
'use strict';
let printNumTwo;
let i;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i;
    };
  }
}
console.log(printNumTwo());
```

Comment: Have you seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var-to-declare-a-variable-in-jav)? I'm sure if you read the accepted answer you could understand how `let` is scoped and hence why the output is different.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this link..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in the scope where `i` was declared.

Declares `i` inside for loop block scope

```js
'use strict';
let printNumTwo;
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // block scope
  // each time we have new variable i
  if (i === 2) { // block scope
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i; // captures the one that was equal 2
    };
  }
}

// console.log(i) // throws ReferenceError
console.log(printNumTwo());
```

Declares `i` in global scope

```js
'use strict';
let printNumTwo;
let i; // globally scoped
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i === 2) {
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i; // captures globally scoped i which will be mutated i++
    };
  }
}
console.log(i) // prints 3
console.log(printNumTwo());
```

**UPD Some docs** [Spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2018/#sec-forbodyevaluation)

> 13.7.4.8 Runtime Semantics: `ForBodyEvaluation ( test, increment, stmt, perIterationBindings, labelSet )` The abstract operation
>   ForBodyEvaluation with arguments test, increment, stmt,
>   perIterationBindings, and labelSet is performed as follows:
>
> 1. Let `V` be `undefined`.
> 2. Perform ? `CreatePerIterationEnvironment(perIterationBindings)`.
> 3. Repeat,
>
> ...
>
> e. Perform ? `CreatePerIterationEnvironment(perIterationBindings)`.
>
> f. If `increment` is not [empty], then ...

Basically new `PerIterationEnvironment` is created before `increment` part. So function will capture `i === 2`.

Comment: // captures the one that was equal 2, But it also increment the i to 3

Comment: "But it also increment the i to 3" not it. But the one created for the next step. You could read about how for loop body is evaluated [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/2018/#sec-forbodyevaluation) Notice step `3.e.` new name binding context is created before `increment` part is performed.

Answer (score 1):

I will explain only the first example because the second is obvious

```
'use strict';
let printNumTwo;
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  if (i === 2) { // block scope
    printNumTwo = function() {
      return i;
    };
  }
}

console.log(i)
console.log(printNumTwo());
```

when you use let inside for loop, it means that the variable i is only defined in the for scope, so in that scope when i is equal to 2 we set the variable printNumTwo, when we do i++ again, i change its value to 3 but it **does not change its value inside the for scope, it remains equal to 2**, which means if somehow if you wanna access the i value, it is always equal to 2

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(i) // prints 0,1,2 
}

console.log(i) // undefined
```

The thing to remember is, even if when i is equal to 2 and we do i++, it does not change its value inside the for scope because i is defined with let